Can I run cable through a wall into a surface-mount box?
I have a surface-mount (1/2” PVC conduit) receptacle in a metal box. Does NEC allow me to run cable through a rear knockout of this box through a wall to wire an adjacent room?

Not exterior. Interior on a workshop wall. This is in a detached building not considered to be for occupancy. The other room is because this workshop, while under 600 sq. ft. (hence not in need of a permanent foundation) has 3 rooms.

As long as you use a bushing in the knockout, I don't see why you can't so that, as long as everything you do outside the box (to the other room) is also compliant..

Presumably (given the type of box) it's an exterior wall. While it's commonly allowed by inspectors (e.g. for exterior lights on a house wall), it's somewhat dubious. All exterior conduit is defined as wet (where "Romex" NM/B should not be, ever), but an exterior box is not a conduit. But it's unlikely to be dry...

@Huesmann Can we assume you meant a NM cable clamp rather than just a bushing?
